# How to multiple echo command in one line?

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I'm dumb to php, but i really need a solution in wordpress

so i've two echo string

```
echo do_shortcode('[google-translator]');
echo '<ul>'.$onepage_menu.'</ul>';
```

I want these to be echo-ed in one line. How?

@sorry about my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo do_shortcode('[google-translator]').'<ul>'.$onepage_menu.'</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP concatenation operator, `.`.

```
echo do_shortcode('...') . '<ul>' . $onepage_menu . '</ul>'
```